# how to make custom directive in angular js using ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to make custom directive in ionic .but I am not able to display same as I do in jQuery ..Actually  I am using hight chart in my application .I got solution in jQuery .But I want to make same thing in angular js .So I make a custom directive for that but I am not able to display my same output as in fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-labels/

I want to display this in my angular as shown in fiddle

I make a angular directive but it is not showing chart could you please tell me where i am doing wrong

here is my code
http://play.ionic.io/app/e953fb83592c

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
app.directive('chart', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        scope: {
      dataArray:"=",
      xAxis_categories:"=",
      title:"=",
      subtitle:"=",
      line:"=",
      yAxisTitle:"="
        },
        template: '<h3>Hello World!!</h3>',
        link: function(s, e, a) {


        }
    };



})

app.controller('cntrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.dataArray = [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]

    $scope.xAxis_categories = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

    $scope.title = "Title";
    $scope.subtitle = "subtitle";
    $scope.chartType="line";
    $scope.yAxisTitle="Temperature (°C)"

})
```

any body have any idea ? why it is not display ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML you need to modify the char tag to display the scope vars:

```
<chart dataArray="{{dataArray}}" xAxis_categories="{{xAxis_categories}}" title="{{title}}" subtitle="{{subtitle}}" chartType="{{chartType}}" yAxisTitle="{{yAxisTitle}}"></chart>
```

In your directive code you need to use the compile and link function for call the existing jQuery plugin and initialize it. Here's a [link](http://henriquat.re/directives/advanced-directives-combining-angular-with-existing-components-and-jquery/angularAndJquery.html) that may help you about combining existing jQuery plugins into directives.

Basically you need to call the initialize function for the chart plugin in the link function of the directive like this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).highcharts(....);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing answer code you please provide answer in fiddle or playionic link

Comment: do you have any idea ?>

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/rootux/angular-highcharts-directive) there is a directive for use Highcharts charts with Angular. Also, you forget to load jQuery in your code.

Comment: Here you have a little working example [http://play.ionic.io/app/4a550bb615ee](http://play.ionic.io/app/4a550bb615ee)